# Naming classes that are properties of main class

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I would like to know how to name constructor function that will be used by my main constructor function, but without the inheritance. Explaining:

I have a constructor function Human:

```
function Human() {}
```

And the human has properties like arms, legs, etc:

```
function Human() {
  this.arms = new Arms();
  this.legs = new Legs();
}
```

I would like to know how to name based on the common usage and conventions the Arms and Legs. If i should use:

```
function Human() {
  this.arms = new HumanArms();
  this.legs = new HumanLegs();
}
```

or:

```
function Human() {
  this.arms = new Human.Arms();
  this.legs = new Human.Legs();
}
```

Comment: It's entirely up to you, either of those (or just `Arms` and `Legs`) would be normal, so long as you are consistent in your code base.

Comment: Side note: All recent versions of Node have a version of V8 that supports the new, more-concise `class` syntax.

Comment: Do things other than humans have arms and legs?

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion, you should consider using the es6 class keyword, with the static keyword

```
class Arms {
    constructor() {}
}

class Legs {
    constructor() {}
}

class Human {
    constructor() {
        this.arms = Human.Arms();
        this.legs = Human.Legs();
    }    
    static Arms() {
        return new Arms();
    }
    static Legs() {
        return new Legs();
    }
}
```

But it all ties down to personal choice

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? What is the purpose of introducing the extra layer of static method?

Comment: @torazaburo base on your previous answer "Do things other than humans have arms and legs".